# botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have one bucket and that's linked with my production environment using python. But I have to backup the production and restore as a testing environment. So,when I also set up the same configuration for s3 with production. But I get this error "botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://mybucketname.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/" ". There is no problem in production. Can't use one bucker for multiple apps?

Comment: The problem is a networking one. The environment does not have network access to the s3 endpoint

Comment: @Paolo I can ping s3.amazonaws.com and telnet s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com 443. There is no issue for these command.

Comment: @Neural what is the bucket's configuration? If you provide CloudFormation / Terraform config for the bucket, it would be possible for us to try and replicate the problem.